# Serialization of an abstract class without [XMLInclude] or Type[] Constructor

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am not sure whether this is possible or not but basically i have an abstract class in NameSpace1[assembly1] and the derived class in Namespace2[assembly2]. Namespace1[assembly1] is referenced by Namespace2[assembly2].

Now i want to serialize the abstract class after creating an object of the derived class from assembly3[only references assembly1].

I googled and found out that i need to specify [XMLInclude()] attribute or provide the type as ExtraTypes in the XMLSerializer Constructor. The current structure of my project won't allow me to achieve that , Can serialization be achieved without the either of the two methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general it is possible.

You can use IXmlSerializable implementation for this usecase. At serialization time you can write down the type of the objects as string into the xml and the objects, properties etc...

For Deserialization you can read the type back from the xml and use Activator.CreateInstance(...) to create the types back again.

Comment: Well implementing IXmlSerializable would be like crazy with so many properties. Hate to say this but any other solutions?

Comment: @SparshGupta Well this depends on your classes you have to serialize and about the compatibility you have to provide (or not) in the future. I like the IXmlSerializable implementation a lot more because for me it is easier to extend/maintain and change the behaviour in the future.

Comment: Thanks @user1341210, just to be sure i would need to implement IXMLSerializable in the base class right?

Comment: @SparshGupta Yes, normally you implement it in the base class. If you need additional things to be serialized, your real "object" classes can overwrite it or you can make some virtual write/Read xml method that can be overwritten optionally to extend the serialization behavior.